# ckEditor does not get resized

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

ckEditor does not get resized according to dimensions provided or resolution. Its editable area carries a default height of '200px' ! and if we try to add dynamic height according to resolution it breaks and doesnt resize itself once the height is given.

Is there any event that can give us any kind of indication or flag that ckEditor's DOM is completely loaded.? If this is possible then i can carry height of toolbar and bottom area deduct it from editor container and give calculated height editabe area.

Would great if any solution provided. I tried 'resize' and exec'Command'

Bad issue! Awaiting positive reply.

Comment: And what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

try,

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

editor.resize( '100%', '350', true );

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
```

This will remove the resize option from the ckeditor.

```
CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = true;
```

This will keep the resize option in the ckeditor.

If you want to specify the resize sizes you can try the following.

```
CKEDITOR.config.resize_minWidth = 500;
CKEDITOR.config.resize_maxWidth = 700;
CKEDITOR.config.resize_minHeight = 300;
CKEDITOR.config.resize_maxHeight = 600;
```

Sizes are in pixels